# Is there any way to reference column with different datatype?

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql

I have 2 schemas/tables as shown:

```
CREATE TABLE schema1.code_tbl 
( code        CHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY,
  description CHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE schema2.record_tbl
( rec_id    VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  curr_code VARCHAR(6),
  remarks   VARCHAR(30)
);
```

I need to create a foreign key reference from `curr_code` in `RECORD_TBL` to `code` in `CODE_TBL`.

```
ALTER TABLE schema2.record_tbl
ADD CONSTRAINT record_code_fk
FOREIGN KEY (curr_code)
REFERENCES schema1.code_tbl (code);
```

This obviously gives me an `ORA-02267` (column type incompatible with referenced column) error.

I cannot alter the code column in `CODE_TBL` because I do not own or control schema1. I cannot alter the `curr_code` column in `RECORD_TBL` because it would break many functions in my application because we don't account for trailing whitespaces.

Is there any other way to enforce referential integrity between the 2 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If schema2 is on Oracle 11g and above, using virtual column may solve your problem, but that will change the structure of your table which you are trying to avoid. If you can manage it, here is how it can be done

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE code_tbl
  2  ( code        CHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY,
  3    description CHAR(30)
  4  );
Table created

SQL> 
SQL> CREATE TABLE record_tbl
  2  ( rec_id    VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  3    curr_code VARCHAR2(6),
  4    remarks   VARCHAR2(30)
  5  );
Table created

SQL> INSERT INTO code_tbl(code, description)  VALUES ('ABC', 'Test Data');
1 row inserted

SQL> INSERT INTO record_tbl(rec_id, curr_code, remarks) VALUES ('1', 'ABC', 'Test Row');
1 row inserted

SQL> SELECT * FROM record_tbl;
REC_ID     CURR_CODE REMARKS
---------- --------- ------------------------------
1          ABC       Test Row

SQL> SELECT * FROM code_tbl;
CODE   DESCRIPTION
------ ------------------------------
ABC    Test Data

SQL> ALTER TABLE record_tbl ADD curr_code_v CHAR(6) AS (trim(curr_code));
Table altered

SQL> SELECT * FROM record_tbl;
REC_ID     CURR_CODE REMARKS                        CURR_CODE_V
---------- --------- ------------------------------ -----------
1          ABC       Test Row                       ABC

SQL> 
SQL> ALTER TABLE record_tbl
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT record_code_fk
  3  FOREIGN KEY (curr_code_v)
  4  REFERENCES code_tbl (CODE);
Table altered

SQL> INSERT INTO record_tbl(rec_id, curr_code, remarks)  VALUES ('2', 'ABC', 'Test Row 2');
1 row inserted

SQL> INSERT INTO record_tbl(rec_id, curr_code, remarks)  VALUES ('3', 'XYZ', 'Test Row 2');
INSERT INTO record_tbl(rec_id, curr_code, remarks)  VALUES ('3', 'XYZ', 'Test Row 2')
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (USER_X.RECORD_CODE_FK) violated - parent key not found
```

Here are the words from Tom Kyte regarding virtual columns:
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:676611400346196844

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tested it on my local setup and it works great. While it remains to be seen if my boss and the DBA will approve of such a measure (altering table structures in production is always a little touchy), I can safely say that technically it's a viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

So the situation is this. You have an existing table `record_tbl` which is well established ( obviously, because changing it "break many functions"). Belatedly somebody has decided to enforce relational integrity on this table but has chosen to do so referencing a table in a different schema with a column of a different datatype.

Hmmmm.

Your options are:

1. Do nothing. Always an option; your application has survived with the current state for some length of time, maybe you can continue to live with the accrued technical debt.
2. Refactor one of the schemas. If you need to enforce the foreign key - and let's face it, relational integrity is a good thing - then you are going to have to change the datatype of one of the columns. Which one you choose is a project decision: changing a column in a schema you don't own is a political problem (initially), and political problems are usually harder than technical problems. Refactoring a schema by changing a column type is a matter of testing, testing, testing.
3. Replication. Build a materialized view in `schema2` which copies the data from `schema1.code_tbl`. Crucially, define the MView `code` column match the datatype of `schema2.record_tbl.curr_code` i.e. varchar2(6). You will now be able to enforce a foreign key against `schema2.mv_code_tbl.code`. **Note:** the data in the MView column will be formatted as CHAR i.e. with trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create relation in different type column.
Why you must create relation in database? You can connect the table using only the code.

Comment: The lessons of history are against you. Enforcing relational integrity in the application rather than the database inevitably leads to data corruption.